# To a senior or superior, do you suggest or do you recommend

Tags: professionalism, communication, colleagues, manager

I am a long time colleague with several coworkers who are senior in position to me.  I am wondering, which term to use when I want to provide my two cents.  Do I the term "suggest" or do I use the term "recommend"?  I know that in the military there was a rule, but that was decades ago. This is an organization which has some prior-military personnel and for those who have not served, most have been around prior-military for much of their work life.
I appreciate your responses.

Comment: How about: "What are your thoughts on doing ..." This way you are not imposing your opinion over their actions and at the same time making them consider what you think

Comment: I don't understand. To me, there is a difference between providing a suggestion and a recommendation. I'm not sure what rule you are referring to, but I guess I don't have enough context. Both seem perfectly valid, depending on if you are making a suggestion or making a recommendation.

Comment: Thanks @GrayCygnus, your input helped me change the wording to "my input".

Comment: @ThomasOwens, thank you for responding. I seem to recall a rule in the military, but I don't recall which way it went.  It was something like 'you suggest to a superior, you recommend to a subordinate" or vice versa.  It's been at least 25 years since I was in the military, so I can't recall which one it was.

Comment: ^ That makes sense to me. As 'suggesting' is offering up a thought, but you're not implying you're right or that they should take your advice. Whereas 'recommend' implies you're knowledgeable enough to say hey, take this advice.

Comment: Do you know that there was a rule (like your question indicates) or seem to recall a rule (like your comment indicates)? It seems like you're overthinking this. Perhaps [this question on English Language Learners would be interesting](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/59230/what-is-the-difference-between-suggestion-and-recommendation).

Comment: @ThomasOwens I remember someone telling me it while I was in the military.

Comment: @linlu: that seems military, yeah. FWIW and in a nutty way, it kind of has things upside down if you look at it from a psychological viewpoint. That is because "I recommend" implies an authoritative "I actually know what I'm doing [and you might not]" and "I suggest" is even more influential - that is, provided the suggestion makes good sense to them and create all sorts of dissonances - in that you the recipient in charge of making their own mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anecdotally, the two expressions sound the same to me, as would things like "raising a potential problem" or "thoughts on ...?" or "input on ...?" or "what about ...?" and a slew of other variations.

In all organizations I've worked with to date you could also openly "disagree with" or even "criticize" and more, provided of course that you then explain why in a constructive manner. Doing so is very helpful for whoever is leading the meeting (and the manager when the two don't coincide) because it allows to improve decisions, helps the team understand the decision's rational and underlying goals, and ideally gets the entire team to make the decision *its own* by involving it in the decision process and funneling it towards desirable outcomes.

On that note, one thing I've seldom seen tolerated is repeatedly pushing to revisit an *already taken* decision that you don't agree with. You only get one shot at expressing your critic: when the decision is being taken or (if taking the decision predated your arrival) when the decision is first explained to you. After that, relentless critics will usually get you fired. Wait until revisiting the decision is on the agenda instead, or until the context has changed so much that it should be.